# assert() showing Warning in php 5.3.1

Tags: php, warnings, sphinx, assert

I am using sphinx 0.9.8 version. My php version is 5.3.1. After integrating sphinx api I am getting some warning regarding assert(). How can I fix that issue?
Any body can help me?

Thanks

Comment: <b>Warning</b>:  assert() [<a href='function.assert'>function.assert</a>]: Assertion failed in <b>D:\myproj\sphinxapi.php</b> on line <b>779</b><br />

Comment: Have a look at `assert_options()`; you may want to switch off `ASSERT_WARNING`. Plus [line 779 of 0.9.8 sphinxapi.php](http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/tags/REL_0_9_8/api/sphinxapi.php?r=2014#779) doesn't contain an assertion, so double-check your version.

Comment: Don't hide that warning ... fix it .. check my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well .. if as a parameter it requires an integer then write your code as :

```
$sphinx->method((int) $param1);
```

Edit : 
Real example :

```
$src = new SphinxClient();
$src->SetServer('127.0.0.1', 9393);
$src->SetLimits((int) $offset, (int) $per_page);
```

See now?

Comment: Hi most of the places they are placing like this "assert ( is_numeric($value) );" This is showing some warnings in my pc. How I will rewrite my codes.